# How to add C dynamic library to existing flutter project?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, shared-libraries, ffi

I've ran into problem trying to add my own small C library to existing flutter application.

Here is error message:

```dart
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'lib.so': dlopen(lib.so, 0x0001): dlopen(): file not found: lib.so
```

Library is working fine, when I call it directly from dart code on local machine, but when I try to add it to existing flutter project on iOS emulator or iOS device, it throws an error above.

Here is ['C interop' official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop):

```
On iOS, you need to tell Xcode to statically link the file:

In Xcode, open Runner.xcworkspace.
1 - Add the C/C++/Objective-C/Swift source files to the Xcode project.
2 - On Android, you need to create a CMakeLists.txt file to define how the sources should be compiled and point Gradle to it. From the root of your project directory, use the following instructions
```

I haven't worked with Xcode, and I want to make it clear. How to do the following step:

```
1 - Add the C/C++/Objective-C/Swift source files to the Xcode project.
```

Here are the things that I don't understand:

1. Do I have to open xcode/call it from command line to add source files to the Xcode project?
2. What is the simplest possible way to add these files `lib.so` and `lib.h`? Is it possible to drag&drop them somewhere, or do I have to do something else?
3. Do I have to modify some settings in files in Xcode, or in other text editor to make this rifles visible to the project?
4. Why is it not possible to simply include `lib.so` and `lib.h` in `pubspec.yaml` file?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hey Danila, I'm having the same issue, have you found a solution? It would be great if you could point me to it (or even add an answer here)

Comment: Sadly, just decided to use dart functionality. Still having this issue